# Unsupported Hardware or Paper Wallet with Parity

Tags: ethereum, wallet, parity-io

Given the vulnerability of all but hardware and paper wallets would anyone know how to use an unsupported hardware or paper wallet with Parity?

I simply want to be able to manually enter an address generated outside of Parity and fully expect to have to bypass the UI and edit a resource file to do so.

*Any ideas?*

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MyEtherWallet](https://myetherwallet.com/) to generate a Paper wallet offline. To do that, you have to:

1. Download the latest release from [Github](https://github.com/kvhnuke/etherwallet/releases/latest). It's usually called `etherwallet-v3.11.3.3.zip` or something like that.
2. (Optional) You can use an USB stick to transfer the wallet to an offline, air-gapped, or live-Linux computer system.
3. On your computer, extract the archive into some directory and locate the `index.html`, open it with your favorite browser. Note, it does not require any working internet connection.
4. Enter a strong password, and make sure you do not forget it.
5. Generate your new Ethereum wallet, make sure you have redundant backups.
6. Consider printing it out.

If you ever want to restore your wallet to spend the funds, you can import it either in MyEtherWallet again, or in Parity. To import it in Parity without using the user interface, you have to:

1. Copy the JSON file into your Ethereum keystore directory on your machine:

   - On Windows: `C:\Users\You\AppData\Roaming\Parity\Ethereum\keys\ethereum`
   - On MacOS: `/Users/you/Library/Application\ Support/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum/`
   - On Linux: `/home/you/.local/share/io.parity.ethereum/keys/ethereum/`
2. Upon start, Parity will recognize the imported key.

*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*